# Кнопка отправки данных Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Суть проблемы заключается в кнопке. Как должна работать она? Кнопка должна быть не активна,до тех пор,пока пользователь не выполнит капчу.После того,как капча была выполнена,кнопка должна быть активна и после нажатия пользователю зачислялся +1 пойнт на баланс. Но кнопка не работает вообще.Ничего не происходит.Почему? Непонятно.Прошу помощи! 
Код кнопки:

```
    <form action="pay" method="post">                               
      <div id="money_captcha_wrapper" class="money_captcha_wrapper">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://moneycaptcha.ru/captcha.php?siteid=33075&charset=utf-8&button=moneycaptchasubmit"></script>
      </div> 
      <input name="moneycaptcha_code" id="moneycaptcha_code" type="hidden" value="">
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить данные" name="moneycaptchabottom" id="moneycaptchasubmit" title="Вам необходимо правильно ответить на капчу"><img scr="/template/images/bottom.png"></>
```

Код,который должен выполняться после нажатия на кнопку:

```
   <?php

   if(!isset($Functions)){
     die("Error! 404");
   }

   $user = $Functions->getUser();
   $payment = '1';

   if(isset($_POST['moneycaptchabottom']) {  
     $result = $Functions->giveMoney($user,$payment);
   }

   if (isset($_POST['moneycaptcha_code'])) {
     $handle = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://moneycaptcha.ru/valid.php?code=$_POST[moneycaptcha_code]"); 
     curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
     $status = curl_exec($handle);
     if ( $status === false ) echo "<br>" . curl_error($handle);
       curl_close($handle);
       $xml = simplexml_load_string($status);

       if ($xml->code == "1"){ //Здесь обработчик клиента}
     }//Конец обработчик клиента
   }
```

Comment: Постарайтесь сократить код,ото нe охотa столько читать.
Вообще это делается следующим образом
1.генерируется capcha, и данные хранятся в сессии

Comment: 2. Когда пользователь набирает капчу,то можно отправлять AJAX и проверять на правильность
3.если true то php код возвращает json например success=>true
4. javascript коде получает succss:true и активирует кнопку 
Но я бы сделал по другому,решил бы количество символов в капче ,например 5,и каждый раз при набирании в input полe капчу подсчитывал бы ,если равно 5 то тогда активировал бы кнопку ,а валидацию проверял бы на стороне срвера ,вместе с остальными данными

Comment: Крч. Капча эта не обычная. Там типо задание выполняешь. Переходишь на сайт,который указан в капче. Делаешь скриншот. Отвечаешь на вопрос. И после 2 вопроса она уже показывает,что всё впорядке и активируется кнопка. Но она почему то не добавляет ничего пользователю. Нажимаю и ноль действий. Вообще не каких. Просто скрыть то я её могу и сделать активной после выполнения капчи,вот только сама кнопка не работает. И в чём проблема не понятно.

Comment: Крч. Кнопка то работает,но вылетает с ошибкой: Страница ******* не работает
Сайт ********* пока не может обработать этот запрос.
Пользователю балл вообще не добавляется.

Answer (score 1):

Кнопка не внутри тэга формы. Если так надо что бы кнопка была вне формы, то нужно указать id формы, и проставить его в параметр в form кнопки.

Comment: так она и так за пределами формы, внимательно посмотрите form br br input type="submite"

Comment: поэтому и не работает

Comment: Кнопка не работает потому что за пределами?

Comment: @PolarWatch не забудьте указать, что мой ответ вам помог, если помог конечно